# Class printDetails printing the wrong Library

Tags: java, class, printing

I'm making a program that prints the names of libraries, and I have almost everything working so far except for a problem where it does not change the library value and keeps printing the same Library when a user enters a different input. Heres what the relevant code looks like:

```
Library UBC = new Library("University of British Columbia");
Library ORL = new Library("Okanagan Regional Library");

System.out.println(+ "Would you like to print a library? (y / n)"");
YesNo(UBC, ORL);

public static void YesNo(Library UBC, Library ORL)
 System.out.println("\nPlease enter the acronym for your library");
 //User enters UBC
 printDetails(UBC);

public static void printDetails(Library LIB){
 System.out.println("\n\t" + LIB.name);
 //Program outputs "University of British Columbia" like it should be doing
 System.out.println("Would you like you print another library?");
 YesNo(LIB, LIB);
```

Now the program asks if they want to print another library, and this is what happens. It runs through the same classes and works properly until it prints the same library again.

```
public static void YesNo(Library UBC, Library ORL)
 System.out.println("\nPlease enter the acronym for your library");
 //User enters ORL
 printDetails(ORL); 

public static void printDetails(Library LIB){
 System.out.println("\n\t" + LIB.name);
 /*Prints "University of British Columbia" 
 when it should be printing "Okanagan Regional Library"*/
```

Does anyone know what to do about this? This problem works vice versa, as in if I enter "ORL" the program outputs "Okanagan Regional Library" but keeps printing that value if you enter "UBC"

Comment: *but keeps printing that value if you enter "UBC"* --> `printDetails(ORL); `

Comment: pls edit code and end the methods appropriately.